# Feedback topology of non-inverting amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback

Regarding feedback topology of non-inverting amplifier, in input we have voltage but how about output? I have seen that everywhere we say its voltage since we give the exact voltage we sense from amplifier to feedback but I don't get why we cant say its shunt since we give all current of the amplifier to feedback and its kind of having a series current in output. Can you explain why its incorrect to say its shunt in output?

Comment: You are speaking of an "amplifier" only. Did you consider that - for example - an OTA (which is, of course, an amplifying device) has a very large output resistance (we say "current output") ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a non-inverting amplifier with gain \$1+\frac{R_1}{R_2} = 2\$. I'm measuring currents drawn from the input (a 3V battery), and drawn from the op-amp's output. I'm also measuring potentials at various points around the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZPdoG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, with an input of 3V, the output is, as expected, 6V.

Now I'll place some extra components for current to pass through, being careful not to change the input potential, or feedback percentage (set by R1 and R2). They are all in the blue box:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGQTk6.png)</sup>

Currents drawn from the battery and op-amp output have both changed, significantly. What hasn't changed are any of the voltages. That's because the op-amp (in this configuration) does not care about currents anywhere. It works on voltages only, and produces a voltage at its output.

The battery produces whatever current it has to to maintain exactly 3V across it, and the op-amp produces whatever current it has to, in order to have its output at exactly 6V.

This is a voltage amplifier. R1 and R2 are not "shunting" current anywhere. If anything, R5 and R4 are both "shunting" current around outside the feedback loop, but this has no effect on voltage input, output or gain.

R1 and R2 form a *voltage* divider. The formula for this particular divider is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{INV} &= V_{OUT} \times \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{2} V_{OUT} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The relationship between input \$V_{IN}\$ and output \$V_{OUT}\$ is:

$$ V_{OUT} = 2V_{IN} $$

Notice that there's no mention of current anywhere in those expressions. The only variables being considered anywhere in this system are *potentials*, and currents have nothing to do with anything here. In fact, it's fair to say that the op-amp and battery are doing a great job of maintaining *potentials* in spite of our pretty good effort to mess up currents everywhere with a stray source and stray resistances.

That's not to say that current doesn't play any role here, of course it does. Current and voltage are intimately related, both being different aspects of the same underlying phenomenon. It's just that in the analysis of this circuit, it can be disregarded, and saying that R1 and R2 act in any way to "shunt" current is meaningless and over-complicating a system concerned exclusively with voltages.

It's often quoted that an ideal op-amp has "zero output resistance" and "infinite input resistance". These "ideal" attributes are intended to relieve the designer of any need to consider current. The inputs draw no current, and the output can produce any potential regardless of how much current is demanded of it.

Of course, if you try to draw too much current from a *real* op-amp output, more than the op-amp can sink or source, then naturally the convenient relationship \$V_{OUT} = 2V_{IN}\$ will be lost. Current would become a consideration, but that is because we are operating beyond the op-amp's capabilities.